# NextAuth + Google Data API

Tags: next.js, youtube-data-api, next-auth

How do I set and get `accessToken` in `NextJS` + `NextAuth`

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
        providers: [
            GoogleProvider({
                clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
                authorization: {
                    params: {
                        scope: 'openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
                        prompt: "consent",
                        access_type: "offline",
                        response_type: "code",
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
        callbacks: {
            session: async ({ session, token }) => {
                if (session?.user && token.sub) {
                    session.user.id = token.sub;
                    session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
                    // session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
                    const firebaseToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(token.sub);
                    session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
                    session.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
                }
                return session;
            },
            jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
                    if (account?.accessToken) {
                token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
            }
                if (user) {
                    token.sub = user.id;
                }
                return token;
            },
        },
        session: {
            strategy: "jwt",
        },
        adapter: FirestoreAdapter(admninDb),
    } satisfies NextAuthOptions;
```

And how to pass it Youtube Data API. App is verified for a scope.

```
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const [subscriptions, setSubscriptions] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchYouTubeSubscriptions = async () => {
      const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

      if (session?.accessToken) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
            {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}` },
              params: { part: 'snippet,contentDetails', mine: true },
            }
          );
          setSubscriptions(response.data.items);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching YouTube subscriptions:', error);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchYouTubeSubscriptions();
  }, [session?.accessToken]);
```